# Fairseq without dictionary

Tags: python, fairseq

I used a Hugging face tokenizer and encoder and preprocessed the data, and now I want to use Fairseq's transformer model for the translation task, but I don't have a dict.txt. What should I do, please

Can only give input and output data fit, or how to make dict.txt

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `dict.txt` file is attached within the pre-trained model. For transformer models, see [Pre-trained models](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fairseq/blob/v0.10.2/examples/language_model/README.md)

Downloading, and extracting `transformer_lm.wmt19.en` gives the following file structure

```
wmt19.en
|- bpecodes
|- dict.txt
|- model.pt
```

Also from the [docs](https://fairseq.readthedocs.io/en/v0.10.2/getting_started.html), the model uses *Byte Pair Encoding (BPE)*. So it you want to train a new model, you might need to pre-process the text first